# Supervised Learning - Predicting a continuous value from a categorical variable as an input, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, machine-learning, neural-network

I’m quite novice to Machine Learning, so I’ m sorry in advance if my question is considered generic.

Currently, I’ m developing a web application (Front-end: Angular2, Back-end: NodeJS) for scheduling doctor appointments. A patient, through their interface, can choose a doctor’s specialty, a day and a time slot in order to make the appointment. They also have to choose their symptom from a dropdown list. On the other hand, the doctor, through their interface, can register in the DB the duration of a completed appointment.

In the patient’s interface, I want to include my Machine Learning Algorithm, which has to get, as an input, a SYMPTOM and predicts the DURATION of the appointment.

I want to be a supervised learning algorithm. It will be able to be trained from inside the Admin Interface, when he wants, with a data set of the completed appointments [specifically with the categorical variable SYMPTOMS (input) and the continuous variable APPOINTMENT DURATION (output)], so the algorithm will know that for example an appointment with a patient with the symptom “fever” lasted for 10 min, another “fever” appointment lasted for 14 min, an appointment with a patient with “infection” lasted for 20 min, another one for 23 min, etc.

Consequently, after training face, the algorithm, given a symptom as an input, has to be able to predict (with neural network or with an equation, e.g. average or something cleverer, I don’t know what, I’m expecting ideas) the expected duration of the current appointment and show it as a message to the patient.

Therefore, my questions are these:

What algorithm do I have to use for my case? Do I need a “contingency table (crosstab)”? I saw this somewhere on the Internet, but I don’t know how to use it?

Is there any implementation of the above algorithm or a library in JavaScript?

Is it easier to make this a classification problem? Instead of calculating a continuous value, to classify the result in one of the following categories: 15min, 30min, 45min, 60min?

Generally, have I addressed the problem right or is there a better handling of it?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Regression

The word you're looking for is "regression". A regression algorithm is a function that maps X = [f1, f2, f3 ...] to Y = [o1, o2, o3, ...] where each o is a continuous variable. The features, f1..fn, can be categorical or continuous or a mixture of both.

#### Implementation

> Is there any implementation of the above algorithm or a library in JavaScript?

Sure, tons of them. Try looking at deeplearn.js

As for what algorithm you want, I suppose that depends on how complex the relationship between variables is. All of these can perform regression. I would try them in this order:

- Linear Regression
- Logistic Regression
- Shallow ANN
- Deep ANN

But let's think about the actual problem for a second. I am not an expert in this field, but I doubt that symptoms have that much of a correlation with appointment time.

#### Counter examples (tangent)

Imagine this: there are 2 doctors at an office. One talks a lot. One doesn't. I go in with a fever and get the one that talks a lot. 1hr appointment. I go in with a sprained wrist and get the one that doesn't talk a lot. 20m appointment.

Or: I go in with a runny nose in winter. So does 50 other people. 3hr appointment. I go in with a runny nose in summer. So does 1 other person. 10m appointment.

In these cases the symptom doesn't account for much of the time taken in the appointment. No matter how great your machine learning algorithm is, it can't learn relationships that aren't there. I would advise caution of this when designing your machine learning problem here.

Answer (score 0):

> Generally, have I addressed the problem right or is there a better handling of it?

I hope my idea can help you. It's is how we approach this problem. Your input to ML model is Symptom. And output is how long appointment is. We can frame this into Regression problem. We don't simply predict Duration based on Symptom name. Instead, we predict Duration based on characteristics of Symptom. First thing first, you have to collect Labeled data to do ML training.

For example, in past several years, you collect 1000 records, each record is for one appointment, with these information:

- Information related to Symptom
- Information related to patient
- Duration of appointment (Label).

After you have data in your hand, you will move to Feature Engineering step which basically does these things:

- Fill missing data.
- Encode Category features. For example, Symptom name has {Cold, Fever, Sore Throat} will become {1, 2, 3}.
- Scaling all features to same numeric scale.

After this step, your data is in numeric format. You can start to use ML. I believe there are a lot of ML library in Javascript. You can google one to use.

After you have a model, in patient's UI, if they choose symptom, we will extract symptom information, patient information, then transform these information into same format as we do the ML training, then ML model can predict how long the appointment is.

This is very high level guide lines, but it can help you come up with a work-version fist. Then you can improve it in later iterations.